# Why is view resizing on aligning by horizontal center in container in Xcode 6?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to align Text Field in View Controller with pressing "align" and selecting Horizontal center in container but then my Text Field get resized. Same thing happened with Image View. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you provide the code you're using to do this?

Comment: I'm not trying to do it over code. I'm doing it in storyboard and watching it in preview.

Comment: A better approach might be to do it in the code... Let me have a think and see if I can figure it out for Storyboard

Comment: It basically gets the width of placeholder.